# What TTL/destination to set on custom domain CNAME mapped to a GAE app?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

Some of my customers have a problem accessing custom domain mapped to a GAE application, they get HTTP 404 error.

What's strange to me, is that they never have the same problem when accessing the application through http://dziennikel.appspot.com URL.

I do not have physical access to their machines but some of the remote debugging is pointing toward a stale DNS cache on some level in their ISP network.

AFAIK I  have correctly setup CNAME (with very short for my taste TTL):

```
host                 type   destination     priority  TTL
app.dziennik.edu.pl  CNAME  ghs.google.com  10        3600
```

Domain is correctly mapped in my Google Apps panel and is working OK for the me and most of my customers.

I am wondering if there is some way to improve reliability, lower TTL or maybe add/change destination to something else (eg. `dziennikel.appspot.com`). What are the  guidelines for that? What mapping settings do you use for your apps?

PS. I know it's not programming related but GAE support moved here and sifting through Google Apps support documents gave no clues.

Answer (score 0):

First, assuming all of the properties are as you desire, I recommend setting your DNS settings and not mess around with them any further.  Yes, you can lower you TTL value (which is currently set to an hour) but if your settings won't change in the future, this isn't a problem.

How long has this been a problem?  I know this isn't a direct answer, but I can state from experience that I've never had a perfect experience setting up domains with my App Engine applications and I've done it 4 times.

My recommendation is to verify that your settings are correct on your DNS and wait it out for 48 hours.  If that doesn't solve the problem.  If your domain still misbehaves, you may request that your customers contact their ISP but that could cost your customers if their ISP doesn't offer free support.

Comment: I have not changed these settings for a couple of months now. This is not something new, as I have been having this issues, form time to time, for 2 years now and on a couple of different domains. I am trying to find a different solution, than blaiming a customer network setup or ISP, and asking a them to change their DNS provider (like change to Google's 8.8.8.8). But if there really nothing _I can_ do then I will recommend a DNS setup change on their PC/router. But I'd like to be 100% sure there is nothing I can do on my end to workaround this problem.